# How to add counter variable to variable name?

Tags: javascript

Pretty straightforward. This is my very inefficient code:

```
var slider1 = new Slider("#survey1", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
})
var slider2 = new Slider("#survey2", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
})
var slider3 = new Slider("#survey3", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
})
var slider4 = new Slider("#survey4", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
})
var slider5 = new Slider("#survey5", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
})
```

I'm sure this can be made way more efficiently, It should go up to "#survey13" but I skipped the rest to save space. Maybe a for loop? How could I add the counter to the name of the variable and referenced id?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can say like bellow

```
var sliders = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    var slider = new Slider("#survey" + i, {
        precision: 2,
        value: 5
    });
    sliders.push(slider);
}
```

So actually your `slider1` is `sliders[0]` and `slider2` is `sliders[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `for` loop to create a slider with the each item. You can add the slider instance in the array and use it later.

```
var options = {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
};
var slider = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    slider.push(new Slider("#survey" + i, options));
}
```

If the plugin support multiple selectors

```
var slider = new Slider("#survey1, #survey2, #survey3 ...", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
});
```

Another way would be assigning a common class to all the elements and using this class to assign slider. As said above, this depends on the definition of `Slider`.

```
var slider = new Slider(".slider", {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with array:

```
var sliders = [];
var cfg = {
   precision: 2,
   value: 5
};
for (var i = 1; 13 >= i; i++)
   sliders[i] = new Slider("#survey" + i, cfg);
```

If you wish to have named variables then go for object:

```
var sliders = {};
var cfg = {
   precision: 2,
   value: 5
};
for (var i = 1; 13 >= i; i++)
   sliders['survey' + i] = new Slider("#survey" + i, cfg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than an array, as the others suggested, is to use an object:

```
var id = 'survey',
    sliders = {},
    i = 13;

do {
  sliders[id + i] = new Slider('#' + id + i, {
    precision: 2,
    value: 5
  });
} while(i--);
```

Then you can use the object you've created: `sliders.survey1`, `sliders.survey2` etc!

Answer (score 0):

you can not change referenced id but you can create it with php before load page

```
<?php
$i=0;
for($i;$i<n;$i++)
{
 echo 'var slider = new Slider("#survey'+$i+'", {
precision: 2,
value: 5
})';}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you introduce PHP?

Comment: @Dave he is new and only wanted to help.

Comment: @sirmagid The questions has the "javascript"-tag so the user is only looking for javascript-solutions. If the user was looking for "php" and "javascript" it would have both tags. If you are good at php, click the "tags" at the top of the page and search for php, questions.